# Relation Between $d$-th Power Residues And Primitive Roots Modulo A Prime

Tags: number-theory

I am trying to understand a paper of P. Erdos and H. N. Shapiro, named as "On The Least Primitive Root Of A Prime". And I am trying to understand the following two parts:

$1)$ Let $F_x(d)$ denote the number of integers among $(u+v), 1\leq u,v \leq [\frac{x}{2}]$, such that $(u+v)$ is a $d$-th power residue modulo a prime $p$. Then  $F_x(d)= \dfrac{1}{d}\sum\limits_{\substack{u\in S \\ v\in S}}\sum\limits_{o(\chi)|d}\chi(u+v)$, where $S=\{1,2,....[\frac{x}{2}]\}$.

Note: an integer $a$ is called $d$-th power residue modulo $p$, if there exists some integer $x$ such that $a=x^d (mod\ p)$ holds.

$2)$ Let $N(x)$ denote the number of integers among $(u+v)$, where $u,v \in S$, such that $(u+v)$ is primitive root modulo $p$. Then $N(x) = \sum\limits_{d|p-1}\mu(d)F_x(d)$.

Note: $t$ is called a primitive root modulo $p$, if order of $t$ is $(p-1)$.

I have tried to verify by considering some special values of $p$ and $d$ only. Please give any hint or provide any related formula which can be used here.

Thanks.

Comment: For $d|p-1$, $\sum_{o(\chi)| d} \chi(a)=d$ iff $a$ is a $d$-th power, otherwise $\sum_{o(\chi)| d} \chi(a)=0$. Then 2) is a Möbius inversion.